# Are methods considered event handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

I'm studying javascript and jquery am a little confused on the proper definition of an event handler.

So far I've read  `.on()` (for example ) is technically a `method` but it is handling events. So would `.on()` be considered an event handler? Or is it an event listener because the function inside of it is the handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, an event handler is what happens when the event fires.  The `.on()` method is the plumbing that wires that up.

So for example, if you have:

```
function dealWithTheClick(){
   alert('Clicked!');
}

$('#someButton').on('click', dealWithTheClick);
```

The function `dealWithTheClick` is the event handler, because it's the function that 'handles' the event that was fired when the click occurred.

Comment: So there is no listener in this case?

Comment: No, a 'listener' and a 'handler' are interchangeable terms in the case of events.  I suppose one could argue that a 'listener' is anything that listens to an event, while a 'handler' probably does something definitive (e.g. does something and then stops the event bubbling or the like), but in practice I've seen them used interchangeably.

Answer (score 6):

No. jQuery's `on` is a method which adds event listeners. It's not an event handler and does not add event handlers.

An [event listener](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-listener) is a function that is [invoked](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-listener-invoke) when a certain kind of [event](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event) is [dispatched](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-dispatch) on a specific element or one of its descendants.

```js
function eventListener() {
  console.log("I'm an event listener");
}
window.addEventListener('load', eventListener);
```

An [event handler](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handlers) is some kind of special event listener:

- An element can only have one event handler at a time for each kind of event
- It is invoked during the bubble phase, not the capture one.
- It can be stored in a [raw uncompiled](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#internal-raw-uncompiled-handler) form which, when compiled, will run with a very weird scope.

```js
function eventHandler() {
  console.log("I'm an event handler");
}
window.onload = eventHandler;
```

```js
var eventHandler = 'console.log("I\'m a raw uncompiled event handler");';
document.body.setAttribute('onload', eventHandler);
```

Comment: `An element can only have an event handler at a time for each kind of event` <-- What does that mean?

Comment: @Musa For example, you can do `element.onclick = handler1`. Then, if you set another handler `element.onclick = handler2`, `handler1` will no longer be called. You can't have multiple handlers simultaneously for the same event type.

Comment: I think you meant to say "only have **one** event handler at a time". I understand the distinction you are making between "handler" and "listener", but informally the two words are used somewhat interchangeably, and a "listener" does "handle" an event in that it can cancel its default behaviour, stop it bubbling, etc. (Also, doesn't jQuery add an event "handler" by your definition if it is running in a really old browser that doesn't support `.addEventListener()` or `.attachEvent()`?)

Comment: Very nice summary of js events!

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, I mean "one", but I think "an" can mean "one". I think latest versions of jQuery no longer add native event handlers, but I haven't looked deeply. However, jQuery only adds a/one native event listener per element and type, which invokes the functions in the jQuery event queue. So one could argue that a native event handler is analogous to the native event listener set by jQuery, and native event listeners are analogous to the functions in the jQurey event queue.

Comment: *I think "an" can mean "one"* - In the right context it can, but it doesn't work in that sentence.

Comment: I think this is overly proscriptive.  I agree with @nnnnnn that they're interchangeable in common use.